# Springbootで「?」が含まれるURLを取得したい

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class GetProjectInfoRestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/test/{opt}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("opt") String opt) {

        return;
    }
}
```

ブラウザで「http://localhost:8080/test/aaa」を実施すると
「@PathVariable("opt") String opt」に「aaa」がはいることを確認できたのですが
「http://localhost:8080/test/aaa?bbb」を実施すると
「@PathVariable("opt") String opt」には「aaa」までしか入っていませんでした。
「?」も含めて値を取得することは可能でしょうか？

また、request.getRequestURL().toString()でURLを取得してみても
「http://localhost:8080/test/aaa」となっているようでした…

Comment: ハテナの後ろはクエリパラメータやリクエストパラメータと呼びます([参考](https://triple-underscore.github.io/RFC2616-ja.html#section-3.2.2))。これを取得する方法は、Spring固有の方法であれば[`@RequestParam`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489124/4506703)になるようです。汎用的には`HttpServletRequest`オブジェクトの`getQueryString()`メソッドで取得可能です([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675191/get-full-url-and-query-string-in-servlet-for-both-http-and-https-requests))(こちらの方法もSpringで実現可能なはずです)。

Comment: yukihaneさま　ありがとうございます。ハテナの後ろが特別なものだと知りませんでした。試しに、@RequestParamを使用してみますと確かに取得できました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PathVariable　はPathに含まれる指定したAliasの値しかとれませんので、クエリストリングを含めることができません。

たとえば http://localhost:8080/test/aaa?bbb=value というURLに含まれる bbbに対応する値を取得したい場合は

```
@RequestParam("bbb") String bbb
```

を引数に含めることで取得できると思います。

また、HttpServletRequest は以下のメソッドをもっています。

> HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL
>   HttpServletRequest#getQueryString

2つのメソッドが返す値を "?" で連結することでリクエストで使用したURLが取得できると思います。
本家サイトの方でHttpServletRequestについての質問があったので、参考にしてください。(回答はこちらも参考にしました)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url

Comment: Daichi Itokazuさまありがとうございます。
getQueryStringを使用しましたところ、?のあとの文字がとれることを確認できました。
今回はこちらを使用したいと思います。